# xed iSuppressing Powershell error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to suppress an error in the following statement:

```
$notes = Get-AdGroup $permissiongroup -Properties info 
$notes | Select-Object -expandproperty info -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

This is to see if there is information in the 'notes' field in AD.

If there is no info, I (logically) get the following error:

> Select-Object : Cannot process argument because the value of argument
>   "obj" is null. Change the value of argument "obj" to a non-null value.
>   At line:1 char:10
>   + $notes | Select-Object  -ErrorAction 0 -expandproperty info
>   +          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], PSArgumentNullException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

How can I suppress this error? SilentlyContinue does not seem to work in any way?

UPDATE
Fixed it with try/catch, thanks.

Comment: Which version of Powershell are you using?  I seem to recall this is a known bug in version 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use powershell try / catch to handle that

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? I cant seem to make it work

Comment: try
{ 
$notes = Get-AdGroup $permissiongroup -Properties info 
$notes | Select-Object -expandproperty info -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
catch
{}

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$notes | ? {$_.info -ne $null} | Select-Object -expandproperty info
```

Comment: This way I am not getting an error but I am still getting output. As the next statement, which is using the $notes variable, depends on whether there is input or no input this will not work.

Comment: @Kevin you need to decide then what do you want, because for what it is shown on the question it is "how to supress the error and move forward", but now you are telling that you don't want to supress the error. If the next statement depends on what the result has then check in that place the properties, cardinality, etc, you require.

Comment: You are right, but what happens now is not what is needed. The error is suppressed but it creates wrong output. If there is output it should return it, which works. But when the info attribute is empty I am getting the other info returned. In a next if/else statement I depend on whether there is some output or not (-eq $null trigger). I hope this makes it more clear :) Thx for the help so far!